# c# sql запрос на вставку данных

Tags: c#, sql

Есть база данных (access), подключенная к приложению, написанному на winforms. База подключена посредством oleDb:

```
using System.Data.OleDb;
```

Есть соединение с БД, всё работает:

```
string ConnStr = @"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=P:\Database\DB\database.mdb";
    OleDbConnection oleDbConn;


OleDbCommand oleComm;
        OleDbDataReader oleRead;
 oleDbConn = new OleDbConnection(ConnStr); //инициируем соединение 
        oleDbConn.Open();
```

Далее делал запрос на выборку, сам запрос подгружался из txt файла:

```
private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //
    {
     try
        {
            string path = @"P:\Database\DB2018\test.txt";

            string s = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).Skip(0).First(); //Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) чтобы не было знаков вопроса вместо кириллицы

            MessageBox.Show(s);
            textBox2.Text = s;

            //

            DataSet ds2 = new DataSet();
           OleDbDataAdapter da2 = new OleDbDataAdapter(s, oleDbConn);

            da2.Fill(ds2, "Spectr");

            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds2.Tables[0];
        }

        catch (Exception d)  
{
    Console.WriteLine(d.Message);
}
}
```

Всё работает, запрос выводится корректно. Хочу по аналогии сделать запрос на вставку данных:

```
 private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //
    {
       try
        {
            string path = @"P:\Database\DB2018\test.txt";

            string s = File.ReadLines(path, Encoding.GetEncoding(1251)).Skip(3).First(); //Encoding.GetEncoding(1251) чтобы не было знаков вопроса вместо кириллицы

            MessageBox.Show(s);
            textBox2.Text = s;

            oleComm = new OleDbCommand(s, oleDbConn);

            oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery();


        }

        catch (Exception d) // ловит исключения
        {
            Console.WriteLine(d.Message);
        }

    }
```

Соответственно ничего не происходит, данные в таблице не обновляются. Подскажите, где может быть ошибка.

Запрос из txt файла: INSERT INTO График VALUES (NULL, P:\SPECTR\Database\схема.png, 3, 5);

Comment: Попробуйте для начала P:\SPECTR\Database\схема.png в кавычки одинарные обромить.

Comment: Это поле гиперссылка, всё равно нужны кавычки? Upd, добавил, всё равно не работает

Comment: Нужно вызывать метод `Update` у адаптера.

Comment: Как я понимаю:  adapter.Update(); Не подскажите, что писать в скобочках в таком случае?

Comment: В скобочках нужно писать `DataTable`, данные из которого вставляются. Но, судя по запросу, данные захардкожены в нём самом. Значит, не используйте адаптер вообще. Используйте метод `ExecuteNonQuery` у `SqlCommand`.

Comment: Я пробовал использовать вместо строки  adapter.InsertCommand = oleComm; строку oleComm.ExecuteNonQuery(); , не работает.

Comment: В программировании нет такого понятия: "не работает". Код не компилируется? Компилируется, но не запускается? Запускается, но падает с исключением (каким?)? Исключения нет, но результат неправильный? ЗЫ: `connection.Open()` - соединение откройте (адаптер его сам открывает).

Comment: Извиняюсь, код компилируется, ошибок не возникает, соединение уже открыто выше и с аналогичным примером на select работает. Просто не обновляются результаты в таблице (не появляется новая строка из запроса).

Comment: Какое значение возвращает `ExecuteNonQuery` - 0?

Comment: Как я понимаю да, никаких изменений нет.

Comment: Исправил в запросе NULL на число в ключевом поле и всё заработало. Я думал, что NULL автоматически увеличивает ключ на единицу.

Comment: Откройте файл базы в Access и проверьте работает ли ваш запрос, а потом уже вставляйте проверенный запрос в код своей программы.

Answer (score 0):

В запросе из txt файла:

```
INSERT INTO График VALUES (NULL, P:\SPECTR\Database\схема.png, 3, 5);
```

нужно писать вместо "NULL" число или указывать столбцы, в которых будут производится изменения для автоматического увеличения счётчика:

```
INSERT INTO График (График_ссылка, Частота_макс, Частота_мин) VALUES ('P:\SPECTR\Database\схема.png', 3, 5);
```